# Compose Text lineheight not respecting includeFontPadding = true

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm on compose 1.5.2, and I notice that Text `lineHeight` is not adding sufficient padding on the top of the first or the bottom of the last line. I think it is effectively ignoring the `PlatformStyle` `includeFontPadding` which is true by default.

e.g using style

```
   val SemiBoldDarkSmall = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = myFont,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        fontSize = FontSize.Small,
        lineHeight = 22.sp
    )
```

Observe the height when only 1 line of text, it is significantly less than 22sp.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, Google is recommending that we override and set `includeFontPadding` false and use the new `LineHeightStyle` API
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/style-paragraph

If you follow this advice then it works as expected:

```
val myPlatformTextStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
    includeFontPadding = false
)
val myLineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
    alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Center,
    trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.None
)

val SemiBoldDarkSmall = TextStyle(
        fontFamily = myFont,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
        color = MidnightBlue,
        fontSize = FontSize.Small,
        lineHeight = 22.sp,
        platformStyle = myPlatformTextStyle,
        lineHeightStyle = myLineHeightStyle
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add outer padding text

```
Text(
    text = "Your Text Here",
    style = SemiBoldDarkSmall,
    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = somePaddingValue, bottom = somePaddingValue)
)

@Composable
fun PaddedText(
    text: String,
    style: TextStyle,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    paddingValue: Dp = 4.dp  // adjust this value
) {
    Text(
        text = text,
        style = style,
        modifier = modifier.padding(top = paddingValue, bottom = paddingValue)
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks, I would have to do this by eye though as I'm not sure of the exact amount of padding that was being applied. I found a nice solution in the end